Why does adding -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo cause a C compiler error in CMake?
I'm new to CMake and trying to build Instant-3D, but I encountered an error. I think this is not directly related to the Instant-3D project itself, but rather a CMake issue, so I'm asking for help here.
After examined the cause, I found that the error when building Instant-3D can be reduced to the following problem:
I have the following CMakeList.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(instant-ngp
    VERSION 1.0
    DESCRIPTION "Instant Neural Graphics Primitives"
    LANGUAGES C CXX CUDA
)

The CMake version is 3.16.3-1ubuntu1.20.04.1.
When I run cmake ., it completes without any erros. However, running the following command results in an error (which seems to be related to C compiler):
cmake . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo

The error messages are as follows:
$ cmake . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.1.74
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /home/**/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/home/**/Documents/Instant-NGP/instant-ngp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-***'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /home/**/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile ***/fast
    no such file or directory
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have checked that the build-essential is installed:
$ dpkg -s build-essential
Package: build-essential
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 21
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 12.8ubuntu1.1
Depends: libc6-dev | libc-dev, gcc (>= 4:9.2), g++ (>= 4:9.2), make, dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11)
Description: Informational list of build-essential packages
 If you do not plan to build Debian packages, you don't need this
 package.  Starting with dpkg (>= 1.14.18) this package is required
 for building Debian packages.
 .
 This package contains an informational list of packages which are
 considered essential for building Debian packages.  This package also
 depends on the packages on that list, to make it easy to have the
 build-essential packages installed.
 .
 If you have this package installed, you only need to install whatever
 a package specifies as its build-time dependencies to build the
 package.  Conversely, if you are determining what your package needs
 to build-depend on, you can always leave out the packages this
 package depends on.
 .
 This package is NOT the definition of what packages are
 build-essential; the real definition is in the Debian Policy Manual.
 This package contains merely an informational list, which is all
 most people need.   However, if this package and the manual disagree,
 the manual is correct.
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>

Does anyone have an idea why adding -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo causes this error and how to fix it?
I will appreciate if you could give me any hints.

So I'm guessing you installed cmake via a python venv because the native cmake for your Ubuntu version (20.04?) doesn't meet the minimum version requirement?

@steeldriver Thank you very much for your comment. I have checked if the installed cmake satisfies the the minimum version requirement, but the result of dpkg -s cmake says it is Version: 3.16.3-1ubuntu1.20.04.1.

OK but the build process itself appears to be using /home/**/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cmake/data/bin/cmake

Thank you for your response, and apologies for any confusion earlier. I've located cmake at /home/**/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/bin/cmake (checked with which cmake), but it seems to be version 3.29.6 when checked with cmake --version. Does the cmake referenced in cmake --version command correspond to the cmake executable located at /home/**/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/bin/cmake? It appears that the cmake reported by dpkg -s cmake is not the same as the one found in /home/**/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/bin/cmake, as you pointed out.
